# Parse error on Input '|'

Tags: haskell, if-statement, where-clause

I looked into every single thread about this error message and tried everything, but it keeps disrupting the compiler. 
My Code:

```
check2 :: Slot -> Slot -> Bool
check2 c1 c2 = if (getTime c1 == getTime c2) | (getSubject c1 == getSubject c2)
                then False
                else True
```

It throws a nice `error: parse error on input ‘|’`

Clarification: all tabs are 8-spaces
As you may guess, the method is part of a more larger method and was in a `where` clause originally. If I put it in the `where` clause, the parse error is on a different place, which is highly frustrating.

Comment: It seems like you want `||` not `|`.

Comment: `|` is a *guard*.

Comment: In C (and some of its descendants), comparisons return the integer values 1 and 0, so you can get away with using the bitwise `|` operator in place of the logical `||` operator. This is a holdover from the languages BCPL and B, which had no logical operators. In Haskell, `|` has no such meaning. It appears in the syntax of guards and list comprehensions. The compiler therefore tries to parse that line as a pattern guard, and cannot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `||` (the binary logical or operator, same as Java) instead of `|`.

You can write your function more directly this way:

```
check2 :: Slot -> Slot -> Bool
check2 c1 c2 = not ((getTime c1 == getTime c2) || (getSubject c1 == getSubject c2))
```

The `|` are used to define function with conditionals. For example, your own function can also be defined as:

```
check2 :: Slot -> Slot -> Bool
check2 c1 c2 | (getTime c1 == getTime c2) || (getSubject c1 == getSubject c2) = False
             | otherwise                                                      = True
```

Comment: Perhaps it is worth pointing out what `|` and `||` mean (the difference between them).

Comment: And, because I can't help suggesting a slightly different shade for the shed, you can apply DeMorgan's laws to get `check2 c1 c2 = (getTime c1 /= getTime c2) && (getSubject c1 /= getSubject c2)`.